# Controller method not defined in laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel, file, controller

I am new in Laravel and trying to learn forms. Currently I am trying to do a file uploading form and my create page looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>   


<body>
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'MovieController@create', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('name', 'Name')}}
    <br>
    {{Form::text('name')}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('description', 'Description')}}
    <br>
    {{Form::textarea('description')}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('release_date', 'Release Date')}}
    <br>
    {Form::date('release_date')}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('country', 'Country')}}
    <br>
    {{Form::text('country')}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('poster_name', 'Poster Image')}}
    {{Form::file('poster_name')}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('file_name', 'Movie File')}}
    {{Form::file('file_name')}}
    </div>
    {{Form::submit('Submit',['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
 {!! Form::close() !!}
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I am trying to make an action of 'MovieController@create'. Now let's see MovieController file:
namespace

```
App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Movie;

class MovieController extends Controller
{

    public function create(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request,[
            'poster_name' => 'required|image'
        ]);


        //Handle poster upload
        $imageName = $request->file('poster_name')->getClientOriginalName();
        $request->file('poster_name')->storeAs('public/images',$imageName);

        $videoName = $request->file('file_name')->getClientOriginalName();
        $request->file('file_name')->storeAs('public/videos',$videoName);

        $movie = new Movie;

        $movie->name = $request->name;
        $movie->description = $request->description;
        $movie->release_date = $request->release_date;
        $movie->country = $request->country;
        $movie->poster_name = $imageName;
        $movie->file_name = $videoName;

        $movie->save();

        $movies = Movie::all();

        return view('home',['movies' => $movies]); 
    }
}
```

At the beginning everything was working but then I made a few changes in create file (only css and visual changes) and now when I try to go to that page, it gives the following error:

> ErrorException
>   Action App\Http\Controllers\MovieController@create not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\MagicMovie\resources\views\movies\create.blade.php)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show me your route file for MovieController@create method

Comment: I have not specified any kind of route for that method because as I have learned if you just put action of controller in form, it will do its job without routes. And it was really working previously

Comment: you are binding controller method to form directly, you can't do that. Define Route in `web.php` assign controller method to it and bind defined route to `action` attribute

Comment: @ZaheerAttar Alright I Just did the next thing: in form I changed 'MovieController@create' to 'http://localhost/MagicMovie/public/add' and in routes I added the following route: Route::post('/add','MovieController@create'); but now it gives the following exception: > Action App\Http\Controllers\http://localhost/MagicMovie/public/add not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\MagicMovie\resources\views\movies\create.blade.php)

Comment: @ZaheerAttar is right. you should define route name on your route.

Comment: @RomnickSusa please see previous comment by me.

Comment: Check our answer, It might help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try doing something like this,

On you form

```
 {!! Form::open([  'action' => route('create_movie'), 
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
```

or

```
 {!! Form::open([  'action' => url('movie/create'), 
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data' , 'method' => 'POST' ]) !!}
```

And on your routes (`web.php`)

```
  Route::post('movie/create', ['uses' => 'MovieController@create', 'as' => 'create_movie']);
```

You can also check some basic Laravel routing [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#basic-routing).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this :

```
Route::post('/storeMovie', 'MovieController@create')->name('storeMovie');
```

in form action

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'storeMovie', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Comment: Found a bit different solution but this also very well works. Thanks.

Comment: @GeorgeTheGood : Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You are binding controller method to form directly, you can't do that.

You should write a Route for it.

in `web.php`

```
Route::post('/add', 'MovieController@create')->name('create_movie');
```

in `form action`

```
'action' => 'create_movie'
```

Comment: It turns out that I should have coded not 'action' => 'create_movie' but 'url' => 'create_movie' because if you type 'action' it starts to search in controller but if you type 'url' it will redirect.